# php variable in sql query

Tags: php, sql, variables

I have this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE hand= " .$_SESSION['SESS_HAND']. ");
```

But always shows "Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or`T_VARIABLE' or `T_NUM_STRING"

Comment: Do you realise that you have a `"` right before your `);` at the end of the string? Making it escape it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always escape string variables :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE hand= '" .
mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['SESS_HAND']). "'");
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your query does'nt work is because the value of your WHERE is'nt between single quotes.

EDIT: Quentin is right too, you did'nt close the quotes at the last bracket ;).

This would make the query work:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE hand= '" .$_SESSION['SESS_HAND']. "'");
```

But like a1ex07 points out, you should allways escape variables! Above query is vulnerable to MySQL injections. Underneath example shows the correct way by escaping the variable, and in my opinion is a bit better readable code ;).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `animals` 
WHERE `hand` = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['SESS_HAND']). "'";

mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM animals WHERE hand= " . $_SESSION['SESS_HAND'];

mysql_query($result);
```

Also, by doing this, you can debug your query and see exactly what it's doing in SQL by writing:

```
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives that error message because you never finish the string that you try to append after the session data: `");`.

Don't build SQL queries by mashing together strings though. [Use prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068).

Answer (score -1):

Problem:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE hand= " .$_SESSION['SESS_HAND']. ");
```

Solution:

```
if (!$sessHand = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['SESS_HAND']))
{ 
echo "There was a error: " . mysql_error();
}
else
{ $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE hand=$sessHand") }
```

Comment: What kind of status message is that?

Comment: Welcome to SO slipfeed! Please try to use a "mature language" here!