# WooCommerce my-accounts Page - get the current user for orders query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to sum specific items for each user, but it seems it doesn't recognize the current user and it sums all the orders for all customers.

How can I solve this? What I am missing?

Here's the code I am using:

```
$order_items = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reports_top_earners_order_items', $wpdb->get_results( "

SELECT order_item_meta_2.meta_value as product_id, SUM( order_item_meta.meta_value ) as line_total FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items

LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id

LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta_2 ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta_2.order_item_id

LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID

WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'

AND posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", array( 'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold' ) ) . "' )

AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'

AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_line_total'

AND order_item_meta_2.meta_key = '_product_id'

GROUP BY order_item_meta_2.meta_value

" ));
$totalPR = 0;
$Products = array(1507, 1406, 1506);

foreach ($order_items as $item) {

 if (in_array($item->product_id, $Products)) {

        $totalPR = $item->line_total + $totalPR;
         echo $totalPR;

    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "doesn't recognise the said user"? Do you get an error? Unexpected output? Something else? Please [edit] the question to include as much information as possible!

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2** - It's working making this:

1. Get the list of the customers
2. Go through each customer in a foreach loop
3. Get the customer ID
4. Add a LEFT JOIN for wp_postmeta table on the post_id:

   ```
   LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS postmeta ON order_items.order_id = postmeta.post_id
   ```
5. insert this 2 lines into your WHERE:

   ```
   AND postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'

   AND postmeta.meta_value = '$customer_id'
   ```
6. Then comes your loop inside the customers loop, to get the sum by customer

**This is the code:**

```
global $wpdb;

// Set here your product ids
$products = array( 1507, 1406, 1506 );
$all_customers = get_users( 'role=customer' );

foreach ( $all_customers as $customer ) {
    $customer_id = $customer->ID;
    $total_pr = 0;

    $query = $wpdb->get_results("

        SELECT order_item_meta_2.meta_value as product_id,

        SUM( order_item_meta.meta_value ) as line_total

        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items

        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id

        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta_2 ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta_2.order_item_id

        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS postmeta ON order_items.order_id = postmeta.post_id

        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID

        WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'

        AND posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", array( 'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold' ) ) . "' )

        AND postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'

        AND postmeta.meta_value = '$customer_id'

        AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'

        AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_line_total'

        AND order_item_meta_2.meta_key = '_product_id'

        GROUP BY order_item_meta_2.meta_value

    ");

    $results = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reports_top_earners_order_items', $query );

    foreach ( $results as $values ) {
         if ( in_array( $values->product_id, $products ) ) {
             $total_pr += $values->line_total;
        }
    }
    echo 'customer ID: ' . $customer->ID . ' | Total PR: ' . number_format( $total_pr, 2 ) . '<br>';
}
```

**Tested and works**. It will output the list with the **`Customer IDs`** and the corresponding **`Total PR`**.

---

References:

- [WordPress Code Reference - get_users()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)
- [php variable in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127667/php-variable-in-sql-query/10127688#10127688)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but it shows no result mate.

Comment: @PatrickJosephAragones On year after, **It works !!!** but this is too late :) … I just wanted to find the solution, so now is done. The answer was to look for the customer ID in the `wp_postmeta` table and not in the `wp_posts` table. See you around…

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
$args = array(
            'customer_id' => $current_user_id
        );
$orders = wc_get_orders($args);
```

You Can Use wp_get_current_user(); for Get Current User And Get Order Data With Args May be It's Work For You.$current_user_id = $current_user->ID;echo $current_user_id;//check current user id get or not`echo $current_user_id;//check current user id get or not`